# Cannot run emulator for Wear OS on Apple M1

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os, apple-m1

I want to start an emulator with Wear OS on my MacBook Pro with M1 chip. When I create a new device and choose WearOS, I see no system image in the "Recommended" tab. However, when I select the "Other Images" tab, I can see this list:

[image: List of system images]

None of the images I chose in the list worked, I always get the message "The emulator process for AVD ... terminated."
Is this still not supported?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, you can use the Wear OS emulator for the Apple Silicon by installing Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Beta2, which was recently released on the beta channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the #wear-compose slack channel

> Not until https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208843522 is fixed

> It is actively being worked on, we hope to have an M1 Wear 3.0 Emulator soon, but no specific dates yet.

Comment: Very annoying, thank you for the info...

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest Android Studio Version. Wear OS Emulator is working now on M1 Macs with the latest Android Studio Bumblebee.